# uninstall apk silently exception---(java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented)

Tags: android, package, uninstallation

I'm developing an application which supports uninstall other apk silently. My device is rooted and the app is placed under /system/app, with reflection i can use the deletePackage method to implement this.
But in the implement of deletePackage method, an exception occurs.The exception informations are as follows:

```
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/JavaBinder(1943): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/JavaBinder(1943): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/JavaBinder(1943):     at android.content.pm.IPackageDeleteObserver$Stub.packageDeleted(IPackageDeleteObserver.java)
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/JavaBinder(1943):     at android.content.pm.IPackageDeleteObserver$Stub.onTransact(IPackageDeleteObserver.java:57)
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/JavaBinder(1943):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/JavaBinder(1943):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
09-20 10:16:02.242: W/dalvikvm(1943): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a461f8)
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1943): FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder Thread #1
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1943): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1943):     at android.content.pm.IPackageDeleteObserver$Stub.packageDeleted(IPackageDeleteObserver.java)
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1943):     at android.content.pm.IPackageDeleteObserver$Stub.onTransact(IPackageDeleteObserver.java:57)
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1943):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
09-20 10:16:02.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1943):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Relative code:

```
public void onBackgroundUninstallClick(View v) {
    PackageDeleteObserver observer = new PackageDeleteObserver();
    if (mPackageManager != null/* && mUninstallPackage != null*/) {
        try {
            mPackageManager.deletePackage("com.example.android.imagedownloader", observer, 0);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}

class PackageDeleteObserver extends IPackageDeleteObserver.Stub {
    public void packageDeleted(boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException {
        Log.i(TAG, "packageDeleted");
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(UNINSTALL_COMPLETE);
        msg.arg1 = succeeded ? SUCCEEDED : FAILED;
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}

IPackageDeleteObserver.aidl code : 

package android.content.pm;

interface IPackageDeleteObserver {
    void packageDeleted(boolean flag);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the app work well on sdk 2.3.5 but 4.0. Maybe the method packageDeleted is changed after sdk 4.0. Can anybody supply the source code of IPackageDeleteObserver.aidl in sdk 4.0.

Comment: void packageDeleted(in String packageName, in int returnCode);//for sdk 4.0

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
```

somewhere missing a method implementation.

```
void packageDeleted(boolean flag);
```

doesn't match the signature of

```
public void packageDeleted(boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException
```

because of `throws RemoteException`

change to

```
interface IPackageDeleteObserver {
    void packageDeleted(boolean flag) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. the method packageInstalled for install apk silently i defined in IPackageInstallObserver.aidl works well.
interface IPackageInstallObserver {
    void packageInstalled(String packageName, int returnCode);
}

Comment: @breeze void packageDeleted(boolean flag); it is public void packageDeleted(boolean succeeded) but isn't public void packageDeleted(boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException. Pls delete the throws RemoteException and you will see or add to interface

Comment: I delete the throws RemoteExceptions , but the same Exception occurs. And i can find the implement of packageDeleted in IPackageDeleteObserver.java, but i don't know why it throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this on both android 2.3.3 and android 4.0.3 emulators and it worked. Note that I've removed the @Override annotation.

I saw some answers indicating an Interface or Abstract Class to decide which one to use, depending on SDK version, but this seems to work as well.

```
class PackageDeleteObserver extends IPackageDeleteObserver.Stub {

    PackageDeleteObserver( ) {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    // android > 4
    public void packageDeleted( String name, int status ) throws RemoteException {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.notifyAll();
            // do your thing
        }
    }

    // android < 4
    public void packageDeleted( boolean status ) throws RemoteException {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.notifyAll();
            // do your thing
        }
    }

}
```